# Android Gradle Plugin produce broken ARR file Flutter

Tags: java, flutter, dart, gradle, sdk

I am developing an application that makes use of a third party SDK, this SDK comes in an example project. I only copied the contents of the libs folder to a new project, Add the library in the build.gradle and it loads without problems, since I can see it in code and use its classes without any exceptions, the problem is that it gives me a *direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file dependencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error). The following direct local .aar file dependencies of the :rfid_c72_plugin project caused this error.*

**Working Build.gradle**

```dart
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.uhf"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.3.3"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            File strFile = new File("/uhf-serial_release.jks")
            storeFile file(strFile)
            storePassword "123456"
            keyPassword "123456"
            keyAlias "uhf-serial-key"
        }
        release {
            File strFile = new File("/uhf-serial_release.jks")
            storeFile file(strFile)
            storePassword "123456"
            keyPassword "123456"
            keyAlias "uhf-serial-key"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        // 自定义apk名称
        android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "UHF-serial_v${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
            }
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.*'])
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
}
```

**Not Working Build.gradble**

```dart
group 'com.example.rfid_c72_plugin'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
    }
}

rootProject.allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 20
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
dependencies {
    //rx Android for updating status
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.19'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.*'])
    implementation files('libs/xUtils-2.5.5.jar')
}
```

**Error**

```dart
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':rfid_c72_plugin:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar'.
> Error while evaluating property 'hasLocalAarDeps' of task ':rfid_c72_plugin:bundleReleaseLocalLintAar'
   > Direct local .aar file dependencies are not supported when building an AAR. The resulting AAR would be broken because the classes and Android resources from any local .aar file de
pendencies would not be packaged in the resulting AAR. Previous versions of the Android Gradle Plugin produce broken AARs in this case too (despite not throwing this error). The follow
ing direct local .aar file dependencies of the :rfid_c72_plugin project caused this error: C:\Users\roysu\OneDrive\Desktop\rfid_c72_plugin\android\libs\DeviceAPI_ver20220518_release.aa
r

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           37.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I'm Trying to build flutter package with the help rfid c72 native sdk.